# Combine sqlite query for multiple conditions

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite table with many columns and I'm trying to provide the user with multiple conditions (i.e options) of accessing. This give rise to a range of outcomes encompassing the below

```
     1  "SELECT * FROM table where apple >= 3 and orange >= 1;" 
     2  "SELECT * FROM table where apple = 0 and orange >= 1;"
     3  "SELECT * FROM table where apple = 4 and juice = 0;"
```

Is there any way to combine all of the above in a single db.query() statement and to prevent duplicate of results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this

```
     SELECT * FROM table where (apple >= 3 and orange >= 1) or (apple = 0 and orange >= 1) or (apple = 4 and juice = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. You save me a heap of unnecessary code lines.